# Adding Realm to pod spec as dependency

Tags: realm

I'm building a cocoaPod for object data storage (Track Cache), and I want to back this pod using the new Realm.io database - http://realm.io

To my (Track Cache) .podspec I've added realm as a dependency, and as a framework:

```
s.dependency 'Realm', '~> 0.81'
s.frameworks       = 'Realm'
```

But I'm still unable to import the Framework in my (Track Cache) pod source code. The line;

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
```

fails in to build as part of the pod I'm developing, although it works fine (and I can use Realm) in any project that has the pod I'm build in it's podfile, in this case Track-Cache-Test app.

Does anyone why this is happening?
If it's something to do with Realm being a framework, how can I use 'framework' pods as a dependency for another pod?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Realm-JSON, which is a CocoaPod that uses Realm as a dependency: https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to look for a good reference, and this is ideal.

Comment: For anyone else that has this issue with frameworks as dependencies, this is solved in Realm-JSON by specifying an exact build number as a dependency:
"dependencies": {
    "Realm": [
      "0.83.0"
    ]
  }
And then Linking specifically to the framework:

"xcconfig": {
    "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS": "$(PODS_ROOT)/Realm/realm-cocoapods-0.83.0/ios"
  }